# electron-packager and electron-builder error build with electron-vue when put in file server

Tags: node.js, vue.js, exe, electron, electron-builder

I'm building an Electron-Vue application from [GREG boilerplate](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue),

Development and build script is working OK (`npm run dev` and `npm run build`), but the problem happens when I put the build result (in .exe package, not installer) in the file server (windows 2008) over LAN network,

The window was opened but blank white.

I tried different parameters :

- building in other template (plain js) -> OK
- packaging it in ASAR -> not OK
- packaging it with electron-builder -> not OK
- packaging it with electron-packager -> not OK
- packaging it with electron-forge -> not OK
- testing for file size for network latency -> should be not a problem, already tried it with bigger file size and working.

Finally I came up with a hack below but I'd like to know if there's any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working by packaging it with electron-builder and `asar=true` option but had to put the whole node_modules directory up in the folder.

```
node_modules
         |
         ----build
               |
               ----The Program (exe)
```

I tried the same way with electron-packager but no luck, so I suspect there's a bug or misconfiguration with electron-packager.

I've read also somewhere you have to build a mini express server so it works on file server but I haven't tried it.